# @SpringBootTest behaves unexpectedly while running tests through maven (surefire)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.1 project and here is the organization of my test classes:

> package com.service in src/test/java

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    ApplicationConfiguration.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest {

 @Value("${bind.password}")
private String PASSWORD;

@Value("${service.client.name}")
private String CLIENT_NAME;

@Value("${service.client.secret}")
private String CLIENT_PASSWORD;

public JsonNode getAgentRequest(String agentName) {
    JsonNode requestBody = mapper.createObjectNode().put("agentName", agentName).put("agentType", "Executioner")
            .put("location", "Seattle").put("agentApiEndpoint", "http://localhost:9090");
    return requestBody;
}



public String getOAuthToken() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    request.set("username", TestConstants.USERNAME);
    request.set("password", PASSWORD);
    request.set("grant_type", "password");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> token = this.testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth(CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_PASSWORD)
            .postForObject(Constants.OAUTH_ENDPOINT, request, Map.class);
    assertNotNull("OAuth token not returned: " + token, token.get("access_token"));
    return token.get("access_token").toString();
}

public MultiValueMap<String, String> getAuthAndJsonHeaders() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headerMapWithAuth = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headerMapWithAuth.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + getOAuthToken());
    return headerMapWithAuth;

@Test
public void postJsonNode(String postUrl, MultiValueMap<String, String> headerMap, JsonNode requestBody) {
    HttpEntity<JsonNode> request = new HttpEntity<JsonNode>(requestBody, headerMap);
    ResponseEntity<String> postResponseEntity = this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity(postUrl, request, String.class);
    assertThat(postResponseEntity.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.CREATED));

}
}
```

I have another package:

> com.service.authentication in src/test/java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    ApplicationConfiguration.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class OAuth2IntegrationTest {

@Value("${bind.password}")
private String PASSWORD;

@Value("${service.client.name}")
private String CLIENT_NAME;

@Value("${service.client.secret}")
private String CLIENT_PASSWORD;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

@Test
public void testOAuthAccessTokenIsReturned() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
   request.set("username", TestConstants.USERNAME);
    request.set("password", PASSWORD);
    request.set("grant_type", "password");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> token = this.testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth(CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_PASSWORD)
            .postForObject(Constants.OAUTH_ENDPOINT, request, Map.class);
    assertNotNull("OAuth token not returned: " + token, token.get("access_token"));
}
}
```

All tests using OAuth token pass in OAuth2IntegrationTest.java when running:

> mvn install

All tests using OAuth token fail in IntegrationTest.java with the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:59541/oauth/token": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode

All tests in IntegrationTest.java as well as OAuth2IntegrationTest.java pass on STS 3.8.1. 
If I move the failing tests to OAuth2IntegrationTest.java from IntegrationTest.java they pass. 
If I move the OAuth2IntegrationTest.java to com.service everything passes including tests inside IntegrationTest.java. I am using:

> maven 3.3.9 which has surefire 2.18.1

I got this hint of moving files across packages from my earlier question:
[@SpringBootTest does not autowire configurations in a deeper package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360602/springboottest-annotation-does-not-work-if-applicationconfiguration-is-extracte)

I have individually run every test on STS with the original setup and they all pass. They fail only on maven. My project setup is exactly like the link with ApplicationConfiguration.java having nothing special. I have no clue how to fix this and looks like a tool/framework issue